# Mediawiki: I need hints how to debug »Exception encountered, of type "ParseError"«

Tags: css, mediawiki, skin

All of a sudden - I have no clue why - our wiki, using the Vector skin, stopped working.

I could see in the network tab of FireFox that one CSS is not used because it isnt html but CSS.

So I tried to load that css alone and it loads as `Exception encountered, of type "ParseError"`.

The path in the url is

`load.php?debug=false&lang=de&only=styles&skin=vector&modules=mediawiki.skinning.interface|mediawiki.sectionAnchor|mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared|ext.wikicategorytagcloud|skins.vector.styles`

By removing the modules and adding them bak in one by one I found that `skins.vector.styles` is returning that error.

I restored the Vector directory with a fresh download but the situation didn't improve. So something which is in our wiki's DB must be causing the issue.

When switching to another skin, no error is observed.

Can anyone please give me a hint how to debug this error? How to find out what's causing the `ParseError`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to view the entire stack trace (used for debugging) of any Exception in MediaWiki, you must add the following line to your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
```

It is advised to set this to false again (or remove it) when you're done debugging. You can find some more information [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgShowExceptionDetails).

Comment: I (think I) did that and it didn't help :(

Fortunately my colleague, who changed the main page the day before, changed it back and now it's working again.

Still wondering what the reason was.